# Is it possible to restore deleted database if i have full umbraco application project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, umbraco

For a few hours I tried to solve this issue. About a year ago I had an umbraco application hosted in Microsoft Azure.

Today it turned out that I have to create the same application for some reason but unfortunately there is a big problem. My database, which was used by the application, has been removed and there is no possibility to restore it (so I was told by a Azure support consultant).

I have an application project and I would like to ask you if there is a possibility to restore the database by having an entire umbraco application project (maybe some files are stored somewhere to restore the database)?

Comment: You should be able to recreate the data from `AppData/umbraco.config' file.

Comment: @DavorZlotrg could explain to me how could i do this because i'm looking for solution whole day and can't find any ?

Comment: that is the cache file umbraco uses. You would have to create a script or an app that parses the content of that file and enters the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restore your Umbraco site without the database. [Here](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/33917-Restoring-without-DB) you will find a reference to a similar question on Umbraco forums.

If you would have exported the database as a bacpac to an storage account or exported it to a computer on-premises, you would have been able to restore your Umbraco site by first importing (kind of "restoring") the bacpac with a new database name and then update the connection string:

```
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mysitesdb;User ID=me@myserver;Password=myPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```